# Validation Generator batch size

Tags: keras, deep-learning

Iam training a CNN on a quite difficult dataset. I got some really good results but noticed that I managed to set the batch size of my validation generator to 1. The train batch size is set to 32 though. If I know change the validation batch size to 32 as well, my results are bad and Iam having a hard time training the network.

I just can't get my head around why there should be any difference in setting the validation batch size to 1 or 32. Iam using MSE as a metric and thought that this is just the mean over all samples.

So why do I get good validation loss results with a batch size of 1 and bad ones with a batch size of 32? Would it be ok to train the model with a batch size of 1 or is my model just overtrained in that case?

Thanks in advance for any advice,

Cheers,

Michael

Comment: You should really take a step back and considering if you are asking the right questions, or even if you are correctly asking questions. You have multiple questions from today and other days where people ask you for additional information (because the question is vague, including this one), but you do not seem interested in that. If you really want solutions then you need to provide all required information. For this question, is very hard to say what is wrong if you don't provide code.

Comment: Mhmm, Iam not sure if Iam able to follow your comment. I feel that I supplied additional information as well as code when I was asked to and I even feel that Iam asking different questions. So using new threads should be ok? Nevertheless I agree that the above question may be somewhat unclear. I just wanted to know why a batch size of 1 in the validation gives me a much lower loss. It feels like keras is only feeding back the loss of the last batch.

Comment: I am trying to tell you that your questions are too vague and most of them unanswerable without additional information. This question is a good example of this.